# maintaining image object visibility with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i am developing a large non-linear powerpoint which has many sub sections to it. This has necessitated a table of contents slide (TOC). in this slide i am representing each section with its own picture. also on the slide are 2 buttons which let the user switch between images. The buttons do this by setting the appropriate section image to visible and all the others to invisible, so that only one sections image is visible at a time. my goal is to make sure that whenever the user goes back to the table of contents slide that the slide displays the same section image each time, regardless of which section what entered the previous time, i.e. the image for section 1 should be visible whenever the user goes back to the table of contents. how do i go about doing this?
also, if i can find new sources to learn more about syntax and other vba coding, i would be most appreciative.

i already consult:

pptalchemy.co.uk

skp.mvps.org

msdn.microsoft.com

i just cannot find more good sites that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the situation, but one possibility:

Add another slide before the TOC.  You could make it a duplicate of the TOC slide (with the image you want in place).

Instead of linking back to the "real" TOC slide, link to this one instead.

On this slide, add a rectangle that covers the entire slide, make it 99% transparent and give it a Run Macro *mouse over* action setting.

Have the macro do nothing more than set the image you want on slide 2 to be visible, then jump to slide 2 (the real TOC slide), eg

SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide(2)

The mouse over macro will trigger as soon as the user moves the mouse, and since that will trigger a jump from one slide to an identical one, it will be invisible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

most of the solution came from [pptalchemy] (http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Auto_Open_Code.html):

I downloaded the [custom ui editor for microsoft office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx)

I added the code from ppt alchemy to the custom ui editor for the slide show.

In vba i added the code:

```
Sub onloadcode()
Debug.Print "Running"
End Sub


Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = SSW.Presentation.Slides("TOC").SlideIndex Then
'code here'
end if
end sub
```

the code executes perfectly now, and i have condensed my table of contents from 9 slides down to 1. Just, don't add features to the code until you have everything in place to accept them. In my case i added the code for text boxes which did not exist yet and that messed up my code a lot. Once i made all of the objects for the code and then added the code it worked perfectly.